# How do I redirect to front-end (port: 3000) from a back-end (port:3001) route in node/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I have all my back-end APIs defined on port 3001 and I would like to redirect to a front-end route which is port 3000. Is there any way to do this?

I know that I can simple do the following

```
router.get(
  "/steam/return",
  passport.authenticate("steam", {
    failureRedirect: "/",
    session: true,
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    return res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
  }
);
```

But assuming that I am deploying this to Heroku which generates its own unique domain, how would I 'dynamically' pass in the front-end route to the application?

Assume that heroku generates `some-domain.herokuapp.com` then I would like to redirect to that domain. But at the same time in my development build I would like to redirect to `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: You can use `process.NODE_ENV` to check if you are in production or not and redirect accordingly.

Comment: @ArchNoob Where would be a good place to define it as either development or production?

Comment: I've defined it in my start script as `"start": "set NODE_ENV=dev && node server"` and I check for that in my routes. I'm assuming this should be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback from `ArchNoob` I was able to solve this by checking for `process.env.NODE_ENV`. This environment variable is set to production when the project deployed to heroku; heroku does this by default.

Then in my passport strategy I did:

```
// port 3443 is for my api routes
const returnURLString =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? "https://my-app.herokuapp.com/api/auth/steam/return"
      : "http://localhost:3443/api/auth/steam/return";

  const realmString =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? "https://my-app.herokuapp.com/"
      : "http://localhost:3443/";
  passport.use(
    new SteamStrategy(
      {
        returnURL: returnURLString,
        realm: realmString,
        apiKey: myAPIKey,
      },
  ...
```

And in my API return route I did:

```
router.get(
  "/steam/return",
  passport.authenticate("steam", {
    failureRedirect: "/",
    session: true,
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev";
    if (env === "production") {
      return res.redirect("https://my-app.herokuapp.com/");
    } else {
      return res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
    }
  }
);
```